# Pandas test reappearance of values based on a rolling period

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ColN']=['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'ABC']
df['ColN_dt']=['03-01-2018', '03-04-2018', '03-05-2018', \
           '03-08-2018', '03-12-2018']
df['ColN_ext']=['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
df['ColN_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColN_dt'])
```

I am trying to solve the following problem based on above DataFrame:
within a window of (say) 5 days, I want to check if `ColN_ext` values are appearing before and after a particular row by group `ColN` .

i.e. I am trying to create a flag:
`df['flag'] = [NaN, 0, 1, NaN, NaN]` . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by defining custom function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

flag_list = []

def create_flag(dt, lookupdf):
    stdt = dt - lkfwd
    enddt = dt + lkfwd
    bckset_ext = set(lookupdf.loc[(lookupdf['ColN_dt'] >= stdt) & \
                 (lookupdf['ColN_dt'] < dt)]['ColN_ext'])
    fwdset_ext = set(lookupdf.loc[(lookupdf['ColN_dt'] > dt) & \
                 (lookupdf['ColN_dt'] <= enddt)]['ColN_ext'])
    flag_list.append(bool(bckset_ext.intersection(fwdset_ext)))
    return None

# Define the rolling days
lkfwd = pd.Timedelta(days=5)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ColN']=['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'ABC']
df['ColN_dt']=['03-12-2018', '03-13-2018', '03-13-2018', '03-01-2018', '03-05-2018', '03-04-2018', '03-08-2018', '02-04-2018']
df['ColN_ext']=['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A']

df['ColN_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColN_dt'])
dfs = df.sort_values(by=['ColN', 'ColN_dt']).reset_index(drop=True)

dfg = dfs.groupby('ColN')

for _, grpdf in dfg:
    grpdf['ColN_dt'].apply(create_flag, args=(grpdf,))

dfs['flag'] = flag_list
```

This generates:
`dfs['flag'] = [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False]`

I am now trying to achieve the same using `pandas.groupby` + `rolling` + (may be) `resample`